# What is a good p-value adjustment for a permutational analysis like pairwise PERMANOVA?

Tags: r, p-value, ecology, permanova

I am comparing plant community responses to experimental treatments using the pairwise.permanova function in R.

However, there are no clear answers regarding which p-value adjustment is good for this sort of analysis. I have seen several folks casually say the Benjamini-Hochberg adjustment, but with little justification.

Thus, I am wondering what a good p-value adjustment for a permutational analysis like pairwise PERMANOVA is and why? I know there will not be a perfect answer, so perhaps an additional question would be: Which adjustments should I avoid?

My code for the pairwise analysis is here:

`pairwise.adonis(bank.plot.nmds_burned, bank.plot.treat_burned$FireGapFence, p.adjust.m ='BH')`

[image: Pairwise adonis output]